# javascript string format check

Tags: javascript

How can I check the format of a string that is built like this

"NL63ZZZ321096450000"

The first 2 characters need to be NL

The next 2 characters need to be numeric

The next 3 characters need to be alfanumeric

The next 8 characters need to be numeric

The last 4 characters need to be numeric

Comment: Use a regular expression. This one would be very easy.

Answer (score 9):

Just use a regular expression:

```
if ( /^NL\d{2}[A-Z0-9]{3}\d{12}$/.test(str) ) { ... }
```

Comment: @dystroy Just was about to change that `2` to `3` :) Thanks.

Comment: Maybe replace `\d{8}\d{4}` with `\d{12}` ?

Comment: OP, I think you might want to pass the `i` flag at the end if you want to allow lowercase alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 1):

^NL - The first 2 characters need to be NL

\d{2} - The next 2 characters need to be numeric

\w{3} - The next 3 characters need to be alfanumeric

\d{8} - The next 8 characters need to be numeric

.* - anything

\d{4}$ - The last 4 characters need to be numeric

```js
/^NL\d{2}\w{3}\d{8}.*\d{4}$/.test("NL63ZZZ321096450000")
```

Comment: Kenneth defined the first 15 characters and the last four. He said nothing what would be between those.